# PHP EXCEL issue in data import with updated excel format .xlxs

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpexcel

I'm using PHPexcel library to import data from excel file to MySQL by using Ajax and PHP. It works fine with the old format excel file `sample.xls` (The Excel 97 - Excel 2003).

But I want to import data from `sample.xlsx` format. PHPexcel not working with this format.

I searched but can't find a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `http://opensource.box.com/spout/docs/` Go through this

Comment: What does "PHPexcel not working" mean in your case? What is the error you receive? I have used PHPExcel  extensively and it worked like a charm with .xlsx files. Try loading the file through the IOFactory: `$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('PATH_TO_FILE.xlsx');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPexcel is deprecated. The library is deprecated since 2015, so I guess that is why they does not support xlsx format. You should use PhpSpreadsheet instead. It supports xlsx format as well.

Here is a good article that explains how to migrate from PHPexcel to PhpSpreadsheet

[Article](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/)

Comment: Better avoid vague statements like "I guess" or "you should" also  link only answers. Use comments instead.